# What has happened to lead moderators to consider striking?

Tags: discussion, moderators, chatgpt, moderation-strike

This is, more or less, for the benefit of the community at large. Not everyone pays deep attention to the inner workings of Stack Overflow, and it may be disconcerting to some to see moderators are [considering a strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) (see also [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000)). I figured I would share things from my perspective (as an elected moderator), and not from the broader moderator team (not all of whom are considering a strike). Other moderators may add their thoughts as they see fit.

I should start by saying that the Code of Conduct change really hasn't played any role. The rollout has been known and well discussed amongst all Stack Exchange (SE) moderators for some time now and Community Managers [had a community discussion in advance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388860/244695). There has been some speculation this played a role, but the SE moderators I know have not really been bothered by it in any significant way. In fact, that rollout stands in stark contrast to what has happened in the last week.

#### A history of Artificial Intelligence policy

In late November of 2022, a company called OpenAI [launched what we now know as ChatGPT](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/11/openai-conquers-rhyming-poetry-with-new-gpt-3-update/)

> On Monday, OpenAI announced a new model in the GPT-3 family of AI-powered large language models, text-davinci-003, that reportedly improves on its predecessors by handling more complex instructions and producing longer-form content.

That, combined with the also recently launched [AI image generator called Midjourney](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/11/midjourney-turns-heads-with-quality-leap-in-new-ai-image-generator-version/), sparked what could only be called a frenzy of new uses for AI-generated content. ChatGPT, obviously, was far more impactful to Stack Overflow, because it could answer coding questions. [People began to openly game the system as a result](https://twitter.com/AndrewRMillar/status/1599067017063313408)

> So I started a new stackoverflow account and I am plugging random questions without answers into https://chat.openai.com/chat and pasting the answer.
> So far, after 9 answers in 1.5 hours it has 1 accepted and 3 upvotes and a reputation of 62...

[And later](https://twitter.com/AndrewRMillar/status/1599151414512480256)

> 6 accepted answers, of the 26, 11 upvotes, 5 downvotes. I am not checking the answers in any way. I'll give it a rest for now and see how we do tomorrow...

That latter comment (about "not checking the answers in any way") exemplifies the problems the moderation team was starting to see *in droves*. People were coming out of the woodwork and, in some cases, becoming coding "wizards" instantly. ChatGPT was printing reputation for some people, and that was the point. Thus we [crafted a new policy for the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/2370483)

> The primary problem is that while the answers which ChatGPT produces have a high rate of being incorrect, they typically look like they might be good and the answers are very easy to produce. There are also many people trying out ChatGPT to create answers, without the expertise or willingness to verify that the answer is correct prior to posting. Because such answers are so easy to produce, a large number of people are posting a lot of answers. The volume of these answers (thousands) and the fact that the answers often require a detailed read by someone with at least some subject matter expertise in order to determine that the answer is actually bad has effectively swamped our volunteer-based quality curation infrastructure.

This was not crafted solely by moderators. We directly involved the [Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/244695), who were not only supportive, but helped us in many ways to get this new policy driven home to the community at large. These efforts included sharing posting behavior analysis and [creating a new Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

> Stack Overflow is a community built upon trust. The community trusts that users are submitting answers that reflect what they actually know to be accurate and that they and their peers have the knowledge and skill set to verify and validate those answers. The system relies on users to verify and validate contributions by other users with the tools we offer, including responsible use of upvotes and downvotes. Currently, contributions generated by GPT most often do not meet these standards and therefore are not contributing to a trustworthy environment. This trust is broken when users copy and paste information into answers without validating that the answer provided by GPT is correct, ensuring that the sources used in the answer are properly cited (a service GPT does not provide), and verifying that the answer provided by GPT clearly and concisely answers the question asked.

The broader policy across the network has been that each SE site got to decide its own course of action ([here's a list of all site ChatGPT policies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384923/244695)). SE declined to make a global policy. Stack Overflow's position has not changed since that time.

#### Ground Conditions

The moderation team uses many userscripts (JavaScript scripts written and maintained by fellow moderators, and running under tools like [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)) to aid in moderation. Sometimes we need a tool and we write one. Other times we extend the existing site functionality. One of them lets us craft our own "stock" moderator messages. We wrote one to inform and/or suspend users caught using ChatGPT.

Another userscript allowed us to run posts against AI detectors like [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/roberta-base-openai-detector), which we and other community members used to detect ChatGPT posts. This system turns out to be important to the issue at hand.

If community members flagged a post, and moderators agreed, the user would get a mod message and/or suspended. The volume we handle every day in some cases meant a user would get a suspension for as few as one suspected post. In hindsight, this isn't ideal (and I won't say moderation mistakes weren't made). And, of course, many users would merely dispute the findings without much in the way of evidence (which is a lot of message replies we get). In some cases, those replies would be ignored, commonly because the reply is rude/abusive and evaluated to be frivolous, but in rare cases because the reply was missed (the tooling for moderators in this area is ... poor, particularly as SO's volume). This, in turn, led them to the [Contact Us form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), and Community Managers (which is the official way to appeal any moderator action).

That brings us to this week.

#### What we have here is a failure to communicate

The normal method to deal with an issue like this is Community Managers will reach out to us in back channels to question the action(s) taken and/or tell us we need to do something different. We can, and do, reverse course when asked. We're all adults, and the atmosphere in most moderator channels is collegial. We are, at the end of the day, volunteers, not employees.

On Monday (a major US holiday), moderators were informed, via pinned chat messages in various moderator rooms (not a normal method), to view a post in the Moderator Team that instructed all moderators to stop using AI detectors (as outlined above) in taking moderation actions. Had it stopped there, it probably would have not been as controversial as it has been. It went considerably further than that, which meant that moderators were all but prohibited from removing content we suspected was AI-generated. Unfortunately, as the Team is private, I cannot share details here.

The fact that it was private was a problem in of itself, in that we were being told to enact a policy that was not available to the broader community. This also undercut any previously supported community policies without any discussion or even the ability to communicate the policy change. After some sites started making public Meta posts out of necessity, [Philippe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe) (Vice President of Community) [posted about it on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/244695)

> In order to help mitigate the issue, we've asked moderators to apply a very strict standard of evidence to determining whether a post is AI-authored when deciding to suspend a user. This standard of evidence excludes the use of moderators' best guesses based on users' writing styles and behavioral indicators, because we could not validate that these indicators are actually successfully identifying AI-generated posts when they are written. This standard would exclude most suspensions issued to date.

This differs **greatly** from the Teams guidance (which, again, we're not allowed to publicly share given its delivery method). To say we're confused would be an understatement. Worse is that CMs have come into the SO mod room to tell us we were violating the Teams version of rules. The only consistent part of all the guidance we've gotten could be summed up as "Delete/suspend for AI posts, just don't say it's for AI posts". In other words, we basically have to vacate the ChatGPT rule, but without saying we're vacating the ChatGPT rule.

On Thursday, Philippe held a meeting in Teacher's Lounge. He admitted the rule should not have been rolled out like that and explained what has precipitated this urgent change (I cannot comment on this point so please do not ask). Their reasons make sense, and explain why SE Staff (himself included) is currently stressed. But he offered no guidance to resolve the split in guidance, and Community Manager comments after he left seemed to reinforce the Teams version, which is far more restrictive on moderators.

On top of all this was a concern that another proposed (and deeply controversial) change that could be highly impactful to the community at large (and drastically increase moderator work) would be rolled out on top of all this. Per Thursday's meeting, this second change was postponed. It's unclear whether it is permanently shelved or merely delayed to a less stressful time. At this time, given the postponement, we cannot discuss this change, since there are no public announcements for it. It might be moot for this, but it still lurks in the back of the minds of most moderators. It is not, however, part of the current proposed strike.

#### What do striking moderators want?

There's a number of issues at play. Some of them merely need an acknowledgement and public repudiation. Others need open comment from SE Staff so we have clarity in what we're expected to do.

1. The ChatGPT rule was a community-crafted and highly supported rule. Staff should not make large scale changes to these rules **solely** using back channels (chat rooms and Mod Team) that are never meant for public consumption.
2. Moderators were being asked to handle flags based on a rule that was not public. Indeed, everything on the site still indicates the old policy is still in effect. As such, we were still getting flags that we could not handle consistent with that policy. The community would have noticed that difference eventually. The few moderators who braved posting about the policy change on their Metas before the public announcement were risking their diamonds and/or access to the Mod Team by doing so. That is deeply unfair to moderators. We have had to go to great lengths to not leak private communications, which has compounded our frustration.
3. Philippe's post poured fuel on that fire with things like

   > Through no fault of moderators' own, we also suspect that there have been biases for or against residents of specific countries as a potential result of the heuristics being applied to these posts.

   This sounds a great deal like an accusation of racism. Nobody wants to be accused of that, inadvertent or not. The private Teams post has a better explanation (with metrics) that avoids that conclusion but, again, it's private. Again, I strongly suspect Staff is merely distracted with larger issues, but that doesn't make this any more acceptable. Moreover, this is just one example of where accusations have been levied at moderators in vague ways that are incredibly hard to take as good-faith discussion on the part of Staff. At best, their words are ill-considered. At worst, they reflect an adversarial view of moderators and the community.
4. Staff has been maddeningly vague on policy (as I've noted, public and private policy differ) and providing instances of what they feel was done incorrectly. They want us to stop using AI detectors as our sole source of action. That's fine and good, but what do we do with someone who posts a dozen (or more) long-format answers in two hours? They're clearly not writing those posts themselves, just bulk answering questions as fast as they can copy-paste them back and forth. Under no policy is this acceptable, but how are we supposed to deal with that? Do we use the new plagiarism tool without direct evidence it was plagiarism? That seems like the wrong tool for the job. Internal guidance suggests removing them as "low quality", but they aren't "low quality" (which is kinda the point of ChatGPT, in that its goal is to make high quality content on-demand). This has resulted in moderators not feeling comfortable in removing these posts and/or issuing suspensions that explicitly say they are violating the ChatGPT prohibition. This is a de-facto reversal of the ChatGPT policy as things currently stand.

#### In conclusion

SE Staff has come a long way from the [great Monica debacle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/244695) of three years ago. In fact, they've been doing some very good things in this vein (I have repeatedly sung the praises of the Staging Ground project, which has had excellent community-to-staff engagement). It's greatly disappointing that we have, in the space of a week, regressed to a point where Staff is firmly at odds with the community that represents their product. None of the moderation team likes having to threaten a moderation strike to get answers, but here we are.

Moderators involved in the strike have already slowed our flag handling. The official strike starts Monday, Jun 5, unless SE Staff can come back and deal with this in a fair and just manner.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information!

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks Machavity. I am completely out of the loop on this, but I've spied a few messages here and there that were (inadvertently) missing a lot of history and context.

Comment: It's somewhat orthogonal to the issue here, but a quick ponderance on volunteerism generally. I derive some pleasure from helping curate on SO, mostly as an editor and a commenter, but I am aware it has become ingrained as an idle habit. I know the corporation behind the scenes doesn't know who the volunteers are - just that there are enough of us daft enough to work for free. I still believe in the aims of Stack Overflow (and it is still the best resource of its kind on the web), but the mounds of rubbish on the site are never-ending, and I do wonder whether it is time well spent.

Comment: I just feel like further contributions are flowers added to a rotting dead corpse, while the sky is spitting acid on me. Up until a week ago, I had full motivation for curating this site. Now it’s all gone. In a certain way, I kind of hope that this is the end, so we can all move on, and continue our community elsewhere, somewhere that we won’t be regularly harassed by the leadership. All these fights with SE are exhaustive and tiring. They’re demotivating, and bad for our health.

Comment: @halfer As a user, and curator, of the site, your voice is more than welcome in supporting those who feel they must take these drastic actions. You are also welcome to join in the strike by avoiding curation activities while the moderators are on strike. Doing so will also help reduce the workload, or at least the backlog, for the site moderators who do not join the strike, if any don't that is. You can declare your intention to join the strike by signing a letter https://openletter.mousetail.nl/ as well.

Comment: Re *"starts Monday, Jun 5"*: Time zones span 26 hours. Is it local time (for each individual moderator)? Or coordinated, like UTC?

Comment: Out of interest, do the moderators have plans for what will happen to the huge amount of work that will be outstanding when (if) this strike occurs and when it (hopefully) end? If this goes on for some time then the volume of flags could be a very tall mountain.

Comment: @ThomA Work like the devil. They know what this is going to cost them. And even then it's probably, in my thinking, less than it could be in a few months if the AI thing stands as is.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Technically on track, though probably a bit broad. I'm not privy to the mod team (network-wide) locations, but I doubt that the extreme ends of the timezone spectrum are represented. There are still plenty of "Mondays" left on the clock though. Some mods may not have the heart to wait that long either. The untold hours of love and labor they've put into maintaining _your_ sites are being discounted by TPTB, in a stressful and, frankly, disrespectful manner.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I kinda have the same thoughts on things as @halfer. I'm just a "regular" user who is using his privileges to curate the content to the best of his knowledge. But in the last few days, it really dawned on me and there's one question in the room: *Why am I still doing this?* orporate clearly doesn't give a sh*t, so why should I? This is probably the frustration speaking, but I wouldn't mind letting SE die in a dumpster fire at this point. Time and time again the people volunteering here were let down, so why still bother? That's why I have signed the letter.

Comment: @QBrute The "why bother" for many, this user for one, is _they_ helped when I needed it, so I help when _they_ need it. _They_ being other users, other developers. What I know, I share. The site is merely the vehicle for the knowledge, and company is the funding for the site.

Comment: @ThomA we burned the flag queue down from around 2000 (ballpark number made public in one of the congratulations posts to the 2022 election results) plus the daily load in a few months. We can do it again. This time the plagiarism backlog is considerably shorter thanks to all the work done in the past months. The flags build-up isn’t nearly a scary prospect compared to allowing unchecked AI crap on the site.

Comment: Hi, folks! Thanks for your interest and comments; we do appreciate them. And I know these are troubling times and we're all a bit out of sorts, but I just want to remind everyone that **the answer box is down there . Please reserve comments only for suggesting improvements to the question**, not giving your opinion. In this case, even asking questions about things that Machavity says here is probably better done as an answer, in order to keep the discussions more focused and avoid unwieldy comment threads. Thanks!

Comment: Lol, 'there is an unrepresentative number of demographic X in jail, this MUST be due to systemic bias against demographic X, no other explanation will be permitted'.  Where have I heard that before?

Comment: I find it difficult to support mods/CM after Monicagate and finding out that I had become racist/misogynist overnight.  Nevertheless, I wiil refrain from posting answers for the duration of the action.

Comment: Is there a plan for publishing a community-led counterproposal here on how AI content should be identified, moderated or discouraged?   Including avoiding discrimination against origin, while also strictly applying the same criteria regardless of origin?

Comment: I didn't quite get what "*moderators were **all but** prohibited from removing content we suspected was AI-generated*" meant. I'm taking "all but" as "far from" (i.e. greatly supported), but I'm suspecting that this sentence intended to deliver something else that I failed to grasp.

Comment: @iBug, being "_all but_ prohibited" means that one is effectively prohibited but the people doing the prohibiting aren't actually calling it a prohibition. "You aren't prohibited from riding my bike, but if you do I'll push your baby sister in to the river."

Comment: Just stubling over this, thinking: "Oh, the naive newbies, who still think stack overflow was about creating a programmer Q/A platform". It isn't. At least, not for the past >5 years. Get over it.

Comment: @Marco13 I've been teetering on the edge of that mindset for years now, but some part of me just won't give in. As tired as I am of it, I'm here to fight one more fight for the good people of this community, because I still believe in our mission.

Comment: "On Monday (a major US holiday), moderators were informed, via pinned chat messages in various moderator rooms (not a normal method)," fails to mention an orange diamond notification was also sent out on the Monday. The notifications used here seems no different to the notifications used for the CoC change, and other policy changes. We were notified of changes to the CoC with an orange diamond notification and a pinned message. "not a normal method" does not seem to be a true statement.

Comment: @Peilonrayz That's true about the orange diamond. What you're missing is that orange diamond messages are no different than any other diamond message, and once they fall out of that list they're gone for good. Unlike mod messages, there's no way to see an orange diamond list after the fact. On SO, we send a lot of mod messages (some of the most active mods are in the UK, and thus not on holiday). So when I saw the orange diamond later that evening, it was long gone. I had to piece together from sticky stars what was going on.

Comment: Very much behind mods here. I'm confused by this, though: You say *"The only consistent part of all the guidance we've gotten could be summed up as "Delete/suspend for AI posts, just don't say it's for AI posts"."* but that seems to contradict what Cody Gray says [here](/questions/424952/424955#comment959803_424963). Then you say *"In other words, we basically have to vacate the ChatGPT rule, but without saying we're vacating the ChatGPT rule."* but the first part would be *enforcing* the rule without saying so, not vacating it. Can you clarify those? *(Sorry if I just need more coffee.)*

Comment: Honestly, @T.J.Crowder, it's complicated, and the problem is that we mods are trying to communicate to the community the reasons why we're frustrated and driven to the point of striking *without* revealing specific details of the information that we were given in private and thus ourselves becoming complicit in breaking trust. All I can say is that staff *did* leave open the door for *potentially* moderating AI-gen content as low quality, but only if it *objectively* is, and that's a problem because (A) scale and (B) there's already been pushback on one of us for trying to do *exactly* that.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray. That explains the apparently contradiction (I suspected it might be something like that). I'm still not understanding the "vacate" part and wondering whether it's just an erroneous word choice in a **very** stressful situation. :-) Power to you folks.  This Absolutely Sucks.

Comment: Are lack of feedback according to [meta-tag:status-review] and/or feature request/bug report in general part of reason of the "missing communication"?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, Machavity.  It's a pity that this isn't as transparent as it should be as it's terribly confusing.  I only found out about this strike when I tried to post in Bad StackOverflow but was not permitted.  Immediately I thought I had done something wrong, only to see Zoe's post.

Comment: It seems like there should be a relatively simple solution to all this. If someone gets repeated flags for suspicion of posting AI content (clearly one ding should not be enough) then they should be temporarily suspended and the burden of proof should be on them to show that they were not AI generated. I suspect the vast majority won't even bother to appeal, which means an immediate improvement. Of those who do try, I suspect most attempts will be clearly frivolous and denied. That should leave a reasonable number of cases where human judgment can be used.

Comment: But if the point of the new policy is to restrict action based on one or only a few data points, or solely on hunches or suspicions, it's hard to find fault in that *on its face*. I guess we have to believe more is going on than folks can tell us, but - as much as I hate the idea of SO being flooded with low quality content (AI generated or not) - I'm not entirely unsympathetic to the concern of people being wrongly punished without meaningful recourse. Add to this the strong possibility of cultural/language biases factoring in and it seems the suits are in a no-win position.

Comment: I'm still on StackOverflow because of my strong respect for Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood, and for their vision. It would be great to hear their thoughts about the AI revolution and how to work with it. I'm not quite as interested in South African private equity (Prosus, the current owner of SO).

Comment: @O.Jones Joel and Jeff both have left Stack Overflow a long time ago.

Comment: Reading the recent [CEO Update: Paving the road forward with AI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/31/ceo-update-paving-the-road-forward-with-ai-and-community-at-the-center/) it appears the plan is to sell Stack Overflow data for training AI.  So you would think this would be a reason not to want the data contaminated with AI generated answers.  Otherwise it's just a closed loop system.

Comment: Even in light of the special circumstances, I'm disappointed that you're deviating from the Q&A style. This is not a question. How can we know that the position presented here is representative of those wanting to strike? I'm convinced a question & self-answer would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @Joooeey To some extent, meta has always played a little fast-and-loose with the Q&A format, especially in the [discussion] tag.  Here, the post sets out a topic, and answers can respond to it.  Writing it as a self-answered question would make it more difficult for people who _aren't_ those mods to respond.  Your concern about not representing the positions of the striking mods is valid, though we've looked through it, one of us edited it to correct some facts, and we can post comments or answers if we have our own positions that differ enough or add enough to merit an addendum.

Comment: @Yogi "...data contaminated with AI generated answers [...] closed loop system." It's not only a closed loop system. There is voting, editing. The whole content gets constantly changed. If the feedback part is only small, it still could be used to improve AI. There is a risk of oversimplifying the situation by just assuming that it wouldn't wok. One could imagine a symbiosis of AI and human generated content, where the AI types the text and we humans check for correctness of the proposed (hallucinated) solutions. If people like to do that is another matter, but it may result in high quality.

Comment: There was not, @Steve. I never answered this question. I answered [this one](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424910), before the strike was even planned. There's also [this answer by Peter Cordes](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424963) who you may be confusing with me for various reasons (similar points of view, avatar colors, subject-matter expertise, etc.) and which mentioned me in the answer body. Peter's answer was written when the notion of a strike had been discuss internally, but not publicly. For me, I am not speaking much in public because I am exhausted from writing so much in private.

Comment: Thanks, @Cody (for this reply, and many others).  It's a mark of how far trust has collapsed that I darkly imagined that an answer (that I thought I remembered)  might have been summarily deleted, or something.

Comment: Thank you for the summary. If you'll have a moment, could you put 3 things that were improved since unjust firing of Monica? This part I disagree with quite strongly with, which led me to strike since then, so I'm curious what you have seen.

Comment: Part of this was used in [an MSE comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395985/if-i-let-chatgpt-improve-a-post-of-mine-linguistically-does-that-count-as-ai-g#comment1324550_396001) (possibly out of context).

Answer (score 87):

> And, of course, many users would merely dispute the findings without much in the way of evidence (which is a lot of message replies we get). In some cases, those replies would be ignored, commonly because the reply is rude/abusive and evaluated to be frivolous, but in rare cases because the reply was missed (the tooling for moderators in this area is ... poor, particularly as SO's volume).

The tooling here is not just poor on the moderator side. The one time I got a mod message, back in 2019, I was caught out by the terrible UI on the ordinary user side, which only lets you send one reply to each message from the mods but gives no hint of this in advance.

It's *not at all* surprising, given that basically broken UI, that users give short replies! The mod message UI renders like a one-on-one chat of the sort users are used to from other applications like WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger, and naturally we expect to be able to send multiple messages as is the norm in such a UI. But that's not how this UI behaves, and instead if you start by writing "Huh?" and hitting *Send*, then your chance to write anything more substantial is gone forever.

Worse, the sidebar of every mod message - regardless of what it's about or whether the mod actually intends it as a suspension threat - states that:

> Our goal is to amicably resolve issues in a constructive way through direct communication. Please note that continuing to persist in problematic behaviors is grounds for timed suspension.

All this gives the false impression to the user that this is going to be a one-on-one, realtime conversation (basically not true in my case, and probably not in most cases), and also that they may be on the cusp of suspension and need to immediately rebut the accusation against them to safeguard their account, without taking any time to compose their thoughts, or indeed to wait for any anger or alarm they feel at receiving the message - natural responses for anyone who has been unfairly accused of something! - to fade.

(It's also aggravating wording in its own right that probably contributes to mods getting angry responses. You can't tell someone you aim to resolve things with them "amicably" and then follow it up with an explicit threat in literally the next sentence! Only crime bosses in cheesy mafia films are allowed to behave like that!)

Worse still, several small bits of evidence over the years have hinted to me that the non-mod user experience of mod messages is poorly understood by the mods:

- Back in 2019, the mod who messaged me denied on Meta that they had threatened me with suspension, even though *every* mod message threatens the user receiving it with suspension - it's right there in the hard-coded content in the sidebar when we view the message! You simply don't have the option of mod-messaging someone without threatening to suspend them.
- Also back in 2019, at least one mod (from another Stack Exchange site) that I spoke to in Tavern On The Meta had no idea the user-facing UI was deceptive in this way and said that it explained the mystery that had always puzzled them of why so many users waste their one reply without saying anything substantive.
- Machavity's post here doesn't give much acknowledgement that the *"frivolous"* replies the mods receive *"without much in the way of evidence"* are probably often *not the entirety of what the user intended to write*, but that after sending their first DM they've been unexpectedly prohibited from completing the thought that they were writing.

In the context of staff concern over people being suspended for a behaviour they're innocent of and then reaching out via the Contact Us form, this strikes me as an issue of great importance! People *should* be able to appeal unfair warnings and suspensions via mod message replies, and this system effectively denies them the chance to do so, leaving them to seek out some other recourse.

There are things that can be done by both staff and mods to improve this state of affairs:

- Staff: fix the user side of the mod message UI! Either make the UI *actually* behave like a chat, and let users send multiple replies without intervening mod messages, or else put a warning into the UI that you only get one reply and show a confirmation dialog when the user sends the message.
- Mods: as long as the point above goes unaddressed in the UI itself, agree a stock warning to include at the end of every mod message you send, warning the recipient that the system only lets them send one reply, and that they should therefore take some time to compose their thoughts before replying.

If - as it sounds like - much of the motivation for conflict here is staff wanting to reduce the number of suspensions and warnings that get appealed to the staff, this seems like an easy win that wouldn't involve lowering our quality standards like the staff's current demand does.

Comment: *"If - as it sounds like - much of the motivation for conflict here is staff wanting to reduce the number of suspensions and warnings that get appealed to the staff..."* I suspect not. The cack-handed way SE Inc did this screams "hidden money reasons" to me. Pure speculation, but one can't help but wonder about Microsoft's role in this. MS is a major investor in OpenAI (the non-profit-with-for-profit-subsidiary behind ChatGPT), and a sponsor (I suspect a major one) on the SE network. The public stance against ChatGPT content was at odds with MS's AI strategy. Was a monetary sabre rattled?

Comment: I must +1 for 'cheesy mafia films'. "That's a nice account you've got there. Would be a shame if something were to happen to it."

Comment: Can you please ask this as as separate question / feature-request? I believe this is breaking away from the particular discussion this question is about.

Comment: Not that that means updating the moderation messaging UI isn't a very good idea. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Aha - that theory makes a lot of sense! Given the mention of bias on the basis of country of residence in the question, I suspected the unspecified secret motive being alluded to was that the company was being sued for discrimination by Indian / Chinese / etc users arguing that they'd been profiled on the basis of the country they were contributing from. But your version of events strikes me as more plausible!

Comment: @MarkAmery - Ah, yes -- that would be a hidden money reason too. So who knows? :-)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Eh, I posted it here because - as I outline in the answer - I thought that it might be an easy technical fix to the main cause of the conflict. Realistically, the staff are never going to fix it unless that was actually correct, so posting a separate question kinda feels like a waste of effort. (Given T.J.'s alternative interpretation, above, I currently guess that I'm wrong and - consequently - that this will never be addressed.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I was starting to think I was the only to whom that was obvious.  It absolutely screams money reasons.  And Microsoft is the most obvious culprit by far, given their ongoing feeble attempts to monetize their crappy AI bot.  And doesn’t have Microsoft also have a Stack Overflow Teams presence?

Comment: @IanKemp The *specific* issue that T.J. and VGR are blaming Microsoft for is very much not one that's been endemic for years; it's *this single recent policy*, and nothing more. And given that we have been told by Machavity that there are non-public motives for the policy that he is aware of but can't disclose, some level of tinfoil-hatted conspiracy theorising is warranted here. We know for a fact that there are secret factors at play behind the scenes, just not what they are - and there aren't *many* salient possibilities.

Comment: @Mark Their theory leaves out the fact that SE's main revenue source hasn't been ads for _years_; Teams is Stack's prime revenue stream. Proposing that _one sponsor_ has enough leverage over the company to single-handedly pressure them into enacting a wildly controversial policy that overrides community norms for the first time in site history is, to me, _frankly preposterous_. That theory sounds to me like it's concocted by folks who do not understand how advertising agreements work, and are looking for someone to blame, so excuse my and others' skepticism towards it.

Comment: I certainly don't blame the tin-foil-hatting of folks given how much we've been left in the dark, but I still think this advertising theory is baloney. There is no way that a moderation policy on Stack Overflow matters enough to Microsoft for it to back-channel leverage its way to forcing the hands of site moderators. Microsoft has way too much else to be concerned about for that to hold water.

Comment: Mark - One small thing: I'm not "blaming Microsoft" for SE Inc's cack-handedness, that's entirely at their own feet. It's just when the "other" party of a disagreement seems to be behaving irrationally, I think it's good to try to understand the kinds of hidden pressures they may be under. And yes, sometimes a bit of speculation about what those might be is useful.

Comment: @IanKemp - Having counted to ten, I'll just say that I hear your concern, but wish you'd expressed it more civilly, and that you hadn't inferred rather more than is present in my comment. I won't go into it further, and wish you well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This isn't about me, you, or our egos. This is about the future of the Stack Exchange community. And unsolicited, unsourced, untrustworthy, unhelpful speculation like yours is exactly the kind of thing that is going to be used as ammunition against this community. So please, for all that is holy - stop.

Comment: @IanKemp You are being wildly rude for T.J.. Even if I were fully convinced of *both* of your reasons for objecting to his comment - i.e. both that his theory about Microsoft involvement is improbable *and* that such a theory being voiced will be used as ammunition against the community in some way - it still wouldn't warrant the tone you're using here.

Comment: @IanKemp I look forward to being proven wrong, when all of this is made public.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's a foregone conclusion that a monetary saber was rattled here, though I doubt it was Microsoft doing the rattling. Stack Exchange network (including Stack Overflow) is not even _peanuts_ to them, financially... maybe peanut _dust_ at best. More likely this is Prosus investors wanting to set the direction for their $1.8 billion plaything that they as yet have been largely unable to "play" with.

Comment: @MarkAmery The UI is indeed awful. In fact, some mods were shocked to learn that the UI appears to non-mods as a "discussion" format for back-and-forth at all--they believed/interpreted mod messages as one-way directives.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could be legal reasons, not [just] monetary. By actively moderating suspected AI-generated content, esp via "detectors", SO takes on a certain liability for both the content that passes muster, and any resulting suspensions. Not a lawyer, but that's my read.

Comment: Other monetary possibility is that SO content is part of the intake of either existing or future/planned gen-AI tools, and so the folks in charge are walking a tightrope between making the community happy (esp mods), and keeping the door open for future "investment/partnerships", i.e. theft of all that free labor.

Comment: @MandisaW Stack Overflow is protected by Section 230 of the Telecommunications Act of 1996 and thus is not liable for any content that is posted on its site.

Comment: @TylerH - Sure, that also makes sense. I'm not quite following you with how much SE is worth to MS financially (the important factor would be the other way around, I'd think; and/or how much *AI* is worth to MS), but it's really not important. Microsoft was one possibility, given the direct AI connection, but just one. My main point is a hidden financial motive being the underlying cause of their behavior, rather than a genuine concern about people appealing suspensions as Mark was suggesting in the answer.

Comment: @zcoop98 - My understanding is that MS's value to SE is not just ads: https://resources.stackoverflow.co/topic/client-stories/microsoft-case-study/ But my main point was a hidden financial motive (MS or otherwise), rather than SE Inc having a genuine concern about people appealing suspensions as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @TylerH Section 230 is under challenge, but it applies to published user-provided content, not the site's internal moderation policies. Notably, it wouldn't preclude lawsuits around unfair/biased suspensions based on faulty accusations of AI use. The protection from liability also requires DMCA-takedown compliance, which would be difficult if we can't tell gen-AI answers from human ones.

Comment: @MandisaW I'm not sure what you mean by Section 230 being "under challenge" (if you mean in the courts, that SCOTUS case is settled), and a site's internal moderation policies are covered under Section 230 as well. The only requirement is that companies respond to and make reasonable efforts to comply with legal requests to remove infringing content when notified of it. It's also not that hard to comply with DMCA takedown requests at scale; most sites do so by just taking down everything that gets a DMCA request against it, which is safer than vetting requests manually and getting wrong.

Comment: @MandisaW No user has ever sued a website for unfair moderation practices, to my knowledge, because matters of Terms and Conditions for voluntarily using a site are, well... pretty _ironclad_ in favor of the operator. You have no _legal right_ to use a site like Stack Overflow, so there is no remedy that a court could provide for being denied access to it. Certainly no one has ever sued a website for unfair moderation practices _and won_. You raise that case in court and your case will be dismissed. Probably with prejudice.

Comment: @TylerH Plenty have tried.  They've lost, of course.

Comment: @TylerH If, as indicated in the original question here, the staff believe that mods are discriminating on the basis of geographic location (and thus, indirectly, on the basis of nationality) when issuing suspension - and are actually voicing that belief out loud in public! - then there may nonetheless be a winnable lawsuit here, either in the US or in the UK where Stack Exchange also has a corporate presence. You may have "no legal right" to access pretty much any private business, but if the denial of access is due to a protected characteristic, it's still a tort.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm pretty sure that geographic location is not a protected characteristic, and arguing it is used as a proxy for nationality would make a lot of large companies that use geofencing to determine the services they provide in a given region very... unhappy. Still, IANAL.

Comment: @MarkAmery Not considering standing, and just looking at the merits, no specific moderators have been named or identified, nor has any specific case of discrimination been identified to weigh whether the statement is factual or not, let alone any of the moderators suffering reputational damage because of the statement. In other words, none of the several standards for defamation have been met even if that is what the company meant/intended when they said that part.

Comment: @Hulk Discrimination based on national origin is prohibited by Title VII, although this isn't a case of an employer discriminating against employees, or even a case involving employees at all. And _Nationwide Mutual Insurance v. Darden (1993)_ strongly argues that volunteers don't have standing to sue for discrimination under Title VII if the employer ever _did_ discriminate in such a way. Though I digress...

Answer (score 30):

Thank you very much for taking the time and writing up all these explanations that give a lot of context to the public. That is much appreciated.

Just to bring the matter forward (a strike should only be a temporary action in order to facilitate some kind of solution, possibly a compromise), it would be good to separate all the involved issues as much as possible. I hope we all can help there.

One issue seems to be possible plagiarism of AI generated content. That should be clarified, i.e. if AI generated content is staying, is it necessary and sufficient to simply cite the generator or what needs to be done there?

Another one is the false positives, that might be difficult to control, especially if complaints aren't followed up all the time. I think it would be helpful if moderators, who know the matter best, make proposals how that false positive rate should be controlled in the future. How should detection of AI generated content ideally look like? What maximal false positive rate are we willing to accept?

> many users would merely dispute the findings without much in the way of evidence

I'm not sure what kind of evidence you were thinking of here. I wouldn't know if I were in that situation what kind of evidence was needed. It might be helpful to describe how people should complain about this specific moderator action, what kind of evidence should be presented. It seems like a difficult problem but in this context it must be solved somehow if AI generated content is to remain banned.

I think with the strike putting additional pressure on achieving a better solution, one should also concentrate on actively working towards a compromise. Just waiting for the company to reverse its last decision might not work out if there isn't a better alternative that ideally would take into account all valid arguments.

Comment: **We cannot compromise with staff when they won't even discuss it with us.** A compromise is precisely what we've been seeking. We (SO mods) have proposed *many* different possible approaches, some of which we're 100% in favor of, and others of which we just see as a "lesser evil", but all of which we would accept in lieu of this harmful draconian policy. Staff has taken an absolutely hardline approach, refusing to even reconsider the policy as currently stated (which, I'll note, is still different in public than in private), and that's only on the one occasion they deigned to talk to us.

Comment: @CodyGray The public doesn't know much about the internal discussions including proposals by the mods how to go forward. We basically have to choose sides a bit blindly. Of course we choose the mods but it may be time to go forward and go public with the proposals. What I missed most from this question here was an alternative to either do it the old ways or do it the company's ways. I think there must be a way to minimize false positives for example.

Comment: We don't feel comfortable revealing details about any of our potential proposals when we can't reveal details of the actual problems/concerns cited by staff, since all of those conversations happened in private, and we don't want to follow staff's lead in breaking trust. I know that's frustrating to the rest of y'all who can't read the private chat rooms, and I'm sorry. I already feel like I have been bordering very much on the edge of saying too much in comments and chat. I'm trying to strike a reasonable balance. I'm sorry if you think it isn't sufficiently persuasive.

Comment: Regarding "false positives", we don't believe there *were* a significant number of false positives, and staff has yet to present us any cases where they disagreed with our handling of them. The argument they're making is, effectively, that there's no way to know for certain, so there's no way to handle them at all. That is not a position that can lead to compromise. It's not even a reasonable position. There are all sorts of things that can be done instead, but the whole point of the strike is to hopefully bring about negotiations and compromise. *Of course* there is middle ground.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike It's fine. You say what you feel is ok to say and leave the rest to whatever happens next. Yes, it's also frustrating for normal users but mostly means that it's difficult to really understand everything and therefore it's a mix of being affected but also only being an observer of a conflict that plays out partly in the dark. I hope you are continuing negotiating and I personally hope a middle ground will be found. That seems to be all I can say until a breakthrough of some sort is reached and published and then I can start commenting again.

Comment: Effectively, SE Inc. is requiring moderators to prove a negative. That's not how ANYTHING works.

Comment: "We basically have to choose sides a bit blindly" No, we don't really. Moderators are community representatives, elected by community, trusted by community. If it comes by choosing which side I should trust, I will always trust what (multiple) moderators say, over to what company says. Also company has proven track record of withholding and skewing the truth, and moderators that are currently involved in the issue have never done that. Trusting moderators is really easy choice.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, we do. What you describe is the very definition of choosing a bit blindly. You have faith in the moderators and have no faith in the company. I would actually not expect anything different from any meta user who is here for more than say a month. I'm just describing what happens.

Comment: @Trilarion I have faith in the moderators because I know them for years. It is not blind faith., it is informed decision based on their previous actions.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Sure. But you do not know all the information that is available to the mods and the company as the primary opponents in this dispute, so your trust or faith will not completely be based on actual information. I prefer to know all the details. This lack of knowledge is what I wanted to convey in the previous comment.

Comment: @Trilarion When I said that I trust the mods, I am not basing my trust on information that I have available in this instance, because like you said I don't have all information. But mods are saying one thing, SE is saying something else. Based on information I had in previous cases and experience with the mods and SE, I trust the mods. Especially when there are multiple mods saying the same thing. I hope that clarifies what I meant. This is why it is called trust.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I completely understand where the trust comes from. Interestingly not all the mods are on strike. It may be that most of the mods who aren't striking are nevertheless supporting it but it could also be that there is still substantial support for the company within the mods. Nobody really knows.

Comment: @Trilarion The most active SO mods are on strike or support the strike. Also my trust in mods is not directly connected with whether they are striking or not. Everyone can have their reason to do one thing or the other. I am also pretty sure that nobody is happy with how company handled AI policy.

Comment: There is no support for the company's position within SO mods. We have mods who are actively striking, mods who support the principles of the strike but aren't actively striking for various reasons, and then mods who haven't logged into the site or are otherwise preoccupied with personal matters and thus haven't expressed an opinion. Claims like "nobody really knows" aren't helpful or accurate. *Someone* knows.

Comment: @Trilarion The flag queue is pushing 2500 unhandled flags. The top flag handler for the last 7 days is [Yaakov Ellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis), whom you will notice is SE staff. He's handled roughly 200 flags in that time span. No, not all mods are officially on strike, but that doesn't mean we don't have solidarity. Nor has anyone attempted to pressure any mod still handling flags into stopping. If any mod wanted to, they could handle flags today.

Answer (score -57):

It could be true that there was bias against users from specific countries and this is sickening to learn. If the suspensions are fair then they should be evenly distributed among all countries. If the data shows that an insane number of users from a country X have been suspended in more than two Stack Exchange sites then someone needs to step in and hold all the mods who suspended the users in that country accountable.

> Through no fault of moderators' own, we also suspect that there have been biases for or against residents of specific countries as a potential result of the heuristics being applied to these posts

There is a lot of truth in the post made by the VP of SE, just because they have decided to make the data confidential doesn't mean they are unfair or biased.
If the mods are costing you a traffic drop of millions of new visitors then the management needs to step in and tell someone to do his job right.

I support the company because they are concerned that someone is suspending too much that its affecting their profits, when the company is already facing stiff competition from Github and chat GPT.
Additional suspensions becomes an internal factor sending users away adding to the already existing problem of stiff competition from Open AI and chat GPT.

Comment: *"If the suspensions are fair then they should be evenly distributed among all countries."* Why? This is only true if it can be shown that the *behavior* of users is *identical* across all countries. There's no reason to believe that that is true. If there are a large number of users being suspended from Country X, it is not reasonable to rectify this by suspending equally large numbers of users from every other country. Instead of evaluating the justness of suspensions based on the outcomes, we should instead evaluate the justness of suspensions *in individual cases*.

Comment: There is so much wrong here, it's embarrassing. 1. Even if there weren't a tendency for some folks in a certain region to exploit the platform more often than others, you are assuming that moderators are looking at a user's nationality to make this decision, or even that they should! 2. The decision from the company was short sighted and will affect traffic in several more magnitudes in the long term. 3. Suspensions are far from fun, you'd better stop presuming that this is all just a game of who upsets the most participants.

Comment: There is also no evidence provided, nor even is the *claim* being made, that "mods are costing [...] a traffic drop of millions of new visitors". The numbers are nowhere near this high. No moderator suspends people for fun. Evaluating all the necessary context and agonizing over the decision to make in each case is literally the opposite of fun.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike, do you really believe that country X is that special to have a high number of suspended users?

Comment: I have no idea. I have never once looked at the country a user was from when deciding to issue a suspension. That's how I know that there's no bias. Your country doesn't matter; your *actions* do.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike, There are 195 countries in the world, if country X has an insane number of suspended users then that's bias.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias to learn what "bias" actually is. Note that moderators have *no idea* where a user is from, *and don't care*. Also, you haven't defined "insane", or given any numbers at all, so your claim is vacuous. Finally, ironically, [outcome bias](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outcome_bias) is exactly what you've fallen victim to in these accusations of moderator bias. The fairness of the *process* is what matters. If there's insufficient evidence to issue a suspension in an individual case, then that suspension is unfair, regardless of any other suspensions.

Comment: Observations like: "There are more suspended users from country X so there is a bias against country X" is a naive observation unless supported by more data. Maybe the reason just might be "There are more suspended users from country X because there are more users from country X" or probably various other plausible explanations.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, But why only country X? This is something that needs to be investigated and if that is done then unfairness will be uncovered and exposed. Truth will remain to be truth even if it's supported by only one person.

Comment: This feels incredibly one sided. Not doing anything against AI plagiarism will *also* significantly affect the traffic of people asking, answering and researching on SO. Notably, unlike AI plagiarism these are the things that actually sets SO apart from many competitors.

Comment: Let me put it this way. When solutions using generative AI like Chat GPT, Bard, etc. were launched they were initially made available only in specific countries (probably not bias but rather due to other reasons). This means for a period of time these models were more available to people from other countries. This obviously means you'll have more users from those countries suspended for using those AI models (other users probably still can use things like VPN to access them at that time). Would you call this as the moderators being biased?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, the generative AI is not bias and not analogous to the stack exchange situation.

Comment: *If the suspensions are fair then they should be evenly distributed among all countries* - not true, a bot net using Chat-GPT to farm SO reputation might use a VPN to globally distribute the apparent origin of the attack.

Comment: @user10186832-eatingpopcorn , a bot net cannot get through the stack overflow bot re captcha scripts. Almost all users are verified humans.

Comment: "If the suspensions are fair then they should be evenly distributed among all countries." Does this take population into account? If there are, for example, twenty suspended users from Pakistan (pop. 250 million) and twenty suspended users from Croatia (pop. 4 million), is that a fair distribution?

Comment: To complicate things further, what if Croatia just so happens to have ten times more programmers per capita than Pakistan does? I recognise and acknowledge your concern on this topic, but there are more variables in play here than just "if you suspend more users from one country than another country then you're racist", which is what you appear to be trying to say.

Comment: @F1Krazy *If the suspensions are fair then they should be evenly distributed among all countries.* perhaps the distribution should take into account the number of internet users in a country and the number of registered SO users in a country.

Comment: @F1Krazy, I think the bias is based on maybe country X having a high number of suspended users across all SE sites which is a red flag.

Comment: If that were true (and nobody but staff knows, because those statistics are not available), would your argument be that *all* moderators on *all* Stack Exchange sites are racist? Would that include moderators who are themselves from "country X"?

Comment: I think I have read somewhere that the "problem" is users who use Chat-GPT to improve their English and therefore the bias is indirectly on a country basis. It depends on the number of proficient English speakers *and* registered SO users *and* internet users. The link is becoming more and more fuzzy.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike, I think racist is a strong and inappropriate word to use but who would argue with users from country x being suspended across all stack exchange sites as a sign that is something is not right.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike what would be interesting is a similar analysis of a "foreign" language site like Spanish Language or SO in Portuguese

Comment: @user10186832-eatingpopcorn, that is the most plausible would be explanation so far, it may be explain the bias claim.

Comment: _Through no fault of moderators' own, we also suspect that there have been biases for or against residents of specific countries as a potential result of the heuristics being applied to these posts_, that sums it all

Comment: No statement with "suspect" and "potential" in it *sums it all* (sic).

Comment: _"in more than two Stack Exchange sites"_ They could have indeed been answering questions with ChatGPT on more than one site at the same time, getting caught in both. Morevoer, some people are known to be stubborn.

Comment: It also speaks _loads_ about this answer that you are so focused on biases from moderators while failing to admit your own biases, nor that AI models have biases of their own.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike,it's no mod's fault, it could be the mentioned heuristics being applied to the posts made by users from those countries.

Comment: @PassionateSE generative AI is relevant because the claim of bias is for suspensions regarding usage of generative AI. If there is inherently a larger number users that use generative AI in specific countries that is not a bias from the moderators. My point was not an analogy at all but rather one of the possible explanations of why more users from specific countries were suspended. Similarly there are more other possibilities. Without the proper data the claim of moderators being biased is entirely unwarranted

Comment: @user Because you're thinking that the same spammers would target the foreign-language sites as do the English sites, thus, effectively removing them from the pool? Otherwise, I don't see what we'd gain from looking at foreign-language sites. Regarding your other comment about users using ChatGPT to improve English, that claim has never been made directly by staff, to my knowledge, and only speculated by some of us in the total vacuum of real data or other convincing evidence. It's my theory that a GPT ban would, if anything, have more FPs on native speakers like myself who write like the bot.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike what are FPs please?

Comment: @user10186832-eatingpopcorn are you talking about this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424712/why-was-this-answer-of-mine-deleted) by any chance? I do believe in that case the user wasn't suspended (only the answer was deleted). I believe FP means False Positive.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no I was not thinking of that question, I don't think I have actually seen a question with a Chat-GPT closure reason before. If I am looking for questions to answer I stick to `VBA`

Comment: @user10186832-eatingpopcorn, that answer was generated by AI and hence deleted for plagiarism and because user pasted response from AI as an answer.

Comment: @user10186832-eatingpopcorn that is actually a meta question asking why an answer was deleted. OP apparently used Chat GPT to refine their answer / correct their grammar.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Abdul has explained what FP (false positives) means. Doh! Taking a single question or answer in isolation I don't think it could ever be possible to identify Chat-GPT content. I think what some people are saying is that when a serial answerer has a history of using English and it suddenly improved around November last year then this is an indicator that they were using Chat-GPT.

Comment: That is certainly *one* of the heuristics that moderators used, yes. There are many others. I don't know why you think it is "impossible" to correctly identify GPT-generated content only in the context of a single post. The mods have definitely been doing that, and we're pretty sure about our accuracy. We are looking into possibly releasing some anonymized information and statistics regarding our results, including the text of posts suspected to be GPT-generated and stats on how we handled those (e.g., suspension, warning, etc.). But unfortunately it'll take *a lot* of time to compile.

Comment: You already asked about the traffic thing: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424977/. The evidence is against you, and you have not been able to refute it. Yet you still stated it here as if the answers there somehow affirmed your position. Please stop ignoring well-supported, objective counterarguments. It's incredibly disingenuous.

Comment: @user10186832-eatingpopcorn - I commonly use tools like Grammarly that likely use some sort of LLM to provide grammatical improvements to your writing.  However, in my experience, the tools being used to detect if a contribution was generated by a LLM correctly identified content ran through a tool like that as being written by a human.  So, I don't believe for a minute that ChatGPT is being used to correct a user grammatical error in their contribution, I do believe, they are using it to generate their contribution in its entirety. *ChatGPT isn't a tool to correct your own grammar errors.*

Answer (score -99):

Although I fully support the moderator team, we have to wonder why this policy change is coming now.

I'm afraid that AI tools will become unavoidable in the near future:

- They will improve the quality of their answers.
- They will become indistinguishable from humans.

Even if this does not reveal to be true in the long term, a lot of people believe it right now.

**These AI tools are quickly becoming a serious threat to the whole SE network**, not only through the poor quality of (some of) its output, blindly copied by negligent users, but also because they present as a competitor: how many people are now using these tools first, before even performing a search?

SE will only have the choice to embrace them or die. Embracing probably implies integrating these tools directly into SE sites, be it through bots or something else.

**My assumption is that this is exactly what Stack Exchange, Inc. is preparing, right now.** Maybe it will just be an experiment, maybe they want to keep it secret for now, but anyway, they are not asking for our opinion. As they will deploy that, it will make no sense to forbid AI-generated content on the site, hence the new policy.

**Edit:** there was indeed [such an experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425162/we-are-seeking-functional-feedback-for-the-formatting-assistant), as I had predicted!

I don't know whether this policy is arriving too early or not – probably they felt some kind of urgency. But, of course, the main issue is that it is being deployed without discussion with the community, treating moderators like children.

Currently, the quality of AI-generated content is still too low, even though it is often useful, so there must be some middle ground to find – and it must be agreed upon by the majority, especially the mod team, if we want it to work properly.

**Let’s hope that the strike leads to a compromise, and a clear understanding by Stack Exchange, Inc. that such unilateral policy changes are not acceptable.**

Comment: 'Currently the quality of AI-generated content is still too low'. We are happy to wait until it matches our quality standards, same as any other contributor.

Comment: This seems like a commentary on future AI in general, but not really the current situation. How does does  this relate to the strike?

Comment: @user1937198 me too, but my feeling here is that there is something deeper that SE is preparing, and they are not waiting for that. They, themselves, fear that if they don’t do it now, they will miss the train, and it will be too late.

Comment: IF the quality of AI answers is similar ot humans i wouldn't be striking, and nor would most people.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am trying to find an explanation for what lead to this situation. The last two paragraphs are directly linked to the strike. This is a [meta-tag:discussion], isn’t it?

Comment: *"They will become indistinguishable from humans."* When (if) that happens then SO will be obsolete because AI will be writing the vast majority of code. A few humans will (probably) continue to write code as a hobby, but I doubt that Stack Overflow Inc will continue to exist just for their benefit. But I suppose that code creation won't be *totally* automated. People will be needed to write prompts for the AI. Perhaps SO will metamorphose into Prompt Engineering Overflow...

Comment: I agree that this technology represents an existential threat to Stack Overflow and most of the the Stack Exchange network. But I believe there is [a third way](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/02/strike_comentary.html). Indeed, embracing non-human content is a pretty effective way to drive askers away from the sites to go directly to the source where those answers are coming from. There will always be a need for human connection and that's one of the advantages AI can never steal from an online community.

Comment: “it is often useful”—No, it isn’t.  Or do you have data to back that up?

Comment: @DidierL At least to me, it seems like only part of the third paragraph ("the main issue is…") vaguely applies to the strike situation. Integrating AI or not is not a fighting point of this strike, so not sure what to make of the first two paragraphs. And I'm not sure what the last paragraph actually tries to say, especially not if those are intended to be statements of fact or just points for discussion. Of course, I might just be misunderstanding what you were trying to say – feel free to [edit] the answer to clarify your point.

Comment: Even if you want to embrace the AI, the generated content has to be explicitly separated from the user-generated content.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, one of the conditions to end the strike is to retract the policy change, so it is absolutely a fighting point of this strike. My answer tries to show that a policy change is unavoidable, and a compromise must be found. I didn’t propose anything specific as I didn’t want to narrow the discussions too much on that. I feel like Trilarion expressed it better than me though :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this should be part of the policy consensus: some kind of disclaimer or maybe a visual separation… But if you fully separate them, it should still be possible for users to improve those answers, and somehow integrate them back with the rest once curated.

Comment: Note that the AI-generated content ban policy has always stated that it was temporary, due to the current poor quality of AI-generated answers. Whether AI will become as good as human-written answers in the future is irrelevant to the current policy.

Comment: _"AI tools will become unavoidable in the near future"_ We'll cross that bridge ___when___ we get to it. Imho, that future isn't nearly as "near" as some people seem to think. Not even close.

Comment: add generated content to an archive site is stupid. Specially most of these generated content is produced using stackoverflow itself, and so "IA" will use its own content to future training, this will blow itself in recursion of non sense answer. Keep generated content outside normal operation of SO is not only better for SO but even for the training of such tool. chatGPT is not intelligent.

Comment: "...my feeling here is that there is something deeper that SE is preparing". I believe the only way they can make their new CoC work is if they get rid of sites like mine where 'AI' generated false information can literally be dangerous and ruin lives. There are several Stack Exchange sites which might be said to qualify under that kind of umbrella.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's the people who think least who "think" that true AI is close.

Comment: If I wasn't on strike, I'd have cast a del-vote on this. I am not trying to be harsh, but have to point out that we are on strike right now, not in future. And speculations about quality of future AI doesn't actually resolve any issues and undermines the concerns that we have **right now**, nor it makes the case for what has been done by SO (Speculations: we all know AI and LLMs are getting better, but to what extent, only time can tell).

Comment: "They will improve the quality of their answers." and "They will become indistinguishable from humans." -- we're nowhere near these situations! ChatGPT answers are painfully obvious and extremely low-quality at the present time. Sure, someday AI might replace humans, but if that happens, there'd be no need for SO anyway. Either way, it's best just ask the AI tool if you want an AI answer and refrain from posting it on SO. After AI overruns other sites, remaining a resource for human expert knowledge is the best possible value proposition in the circumstances.

Comment: Underrated answer, can't believe you got downvoted into oblivion like that, completely undeserved. You showed proper respect for the mods, you're just speculating on what Stack's motives might be, I feel like that's allowed. Don't shoot the messenger guys.

Comment: @BrockBrown it's simply not relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @KevinB From what I understand, the fact that Stack refuses to negotiate the AI related policies with mods is a major reason why the mods are striking. I think it pierces the heart of the discussion.

Comment: While the strike is ai related, ai improving and rendering so obsolete is not relevant to stack’s mismanagement of the policy being rolled out.

Comment: @KevinB What Didier is arguing if I interpret it correctly is that the mismanagement happened because Stack is trying its darnedest not to become obsolete. In my own wild speculation, Stack didn't see room for negotiation on that front because there's a general disdain from SO users for any notion of AI replacing programmers. Many of SO's users have been doing programming for a living for years. It all boils down to livelihood. Stack wants to live as long as it can while simultaneously avoiding the discussion of it possibly being a contributor to a serious, measurable loss of programming jobs.

Comment: Again, that’s just speculation and not relevant to the strike.

Comment: @KevinB The strike happened because of the mismanagement. Speculation is okay, this is a discussion

Comment: Noone said speculation wasn't ok; When and how (and if it's already the case) SO becomes irrelevant simply isn't relevant to what happened that lead to moderators considering a strike. We aren't as a group anti-AI, rather, we care for the quality and success of the community (which in some cases may differ from the company's monetary needs)

Comment: @KevinB I'm really trying to understand because I think it's important, why do you feel it's irrelevant? MisterMiyagi says that it's because it feels like it's a general commentary on the future of AI, do you feel similarly?

Comment: effectively, it's stating an opinion that noone can effectively discuss because it's an answer on a question where the opinion doesn't belong. There's no room here to dispute it or offer alternatives, it's not in any way answering the question asked. It's likely already been posted in full on the "we're banning AI Generated Answers" post.

Comment: Put another way: Not every meta post that exists that briefly mentions AI needs an "AI is replacing SO" answer. We get it. We see it every day, it's irrelevant to the discussion we're having on this question.

Comment: This answer more or less paints the entire issue here as if it's some us vs ai, when in fact it's no where near that clear. The whole point of SO is to have long-standing useful answers, copy pasting answers from GPT without knowing whether or not they're correct misses the point entirely and diminishes the value of the network as a whole. That is what we're fighting against. If people want to go to chatgpt to ask their questions, that's fine. It only becomes a burden when that drives the company to make decisions that get in the way of the community's goals.

Comment: It's worth noting that you cannot look at current trends and extrapolate with certainty. That's literally trying to predict the future, and we all know how well that turns out. So yeah, _maybe_ AI tools will continue on the current trend and reach the point of actually being useful and reliable, but maybe we're nearing the top of the S-curve of progress and they won't get much better. It's impossible to know. Personally I tend to think they can't get a whole lot better because of how they work, but who knows.

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much?

Comment: @user13267 Read the comments above. It's a baseless speculation on what the future holds, and has nothing to do with the current situation.

Comment: @PasserBy I've read the comments. He's allowed to state his opinion. Don't get the downvotes

Comment: @user13267 The "nothing to do with the current situation" part is why it's downvoted: it doesn't answer the question, even if this might be a reasonable answer to another question. Answer, as in, participating to the same discussion, since this is meta.

Comment: What do you mean you "don't get the downvotes"? There are at least a dozen people explaining in the comments why they disagree with the answer. Those are the reasons for the downvotes. No one said he's not allowed to state his opinions.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike + Passerby  Why is this downvoted so much? = I disagree with the downvotes.  so participating in the same discussion means he has to just post something that agrees with whatever the OP is talking about? Whatever justification people may be giving here, it doesn't deserve all the downvotes it is getting.

Comment: @user13267 It means the answer should be part of the discussion topic of this meta Q&A, not some other topic. The strike is not about a hypothetical future AI performance and policy regarding it, so literally 90%+ of this post misses the topic.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So he's supposed to have posted something agreeing with OP? Some users are threatening to strike, he is trying to give his understanding of why stackoverflow might have taken the decision, that lead to the said threat of strike. Even has a note of support at the end, hoping that this will lead to SO understanding unilateral policy changes are not acceptable. I don't see why that is deserving of this many downvotes.

Comment: @user13267 "So he's supposed to have posted something agreeing with OP" The very comment you replied to clarified that's not it. Feel free to disagree whether the answer matches the topic or not, but please refrain from alleging there would be a different motivation when people have gone to great lengths to state what their motivation is.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I never said anything about anyone's motivation, I stated I don't agree with all the downvotes, regardless of whatever justification people are giving here for them. I don't agree with most of said justifications either. I know I'm free to disagree whether the answer matches the topic or not, and I stated I do.

Comment: "They will improve the quality of their answers." You are kind of missing the point that in order for an AI to provide good programming answers, it must be trained on something. There is no magic involved, the AI cannot get better without human input. And as it happens, there aren't a lot of other credible programming resources elsewhere online to train it on. Now, if AI generated content is fed as input to the AI, then it will get stuck in a recursive loop where it gets _worse_ with every iteration, not better. And from there both SO and the AI will get _worse_.

Comment: “*how many people are now using these tools first, before even performing a search?*”—So you’re assuming that finally, users will do their own research before coming to Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Holger people will go to where it's easiest to get an answer, ChatGPT allows you to get an answer without doing a search, so it even beats FGITW! I was actually thinking about it more today, if SO would generate an AI answer (as a community wiki with proper disclaimer) automatically for questions (maybe not for all tags), it would resolve both the FGITW problem and the current AI issue (what would be the point of posting an additional, almost identical AI answer?), and people could focus on improving those answers or tackling the more advanced, interesting questions.

Comment: Anyway, that's not really the point of my answer. The point is that SE seems to be preparing something, whether we want it or not. I agree it is speculation, and I understand that people don't like it.

Comment: I don't disagree that they're probably preparing something, but i doubt it's literally implementing a GPT-like answer generator. Some of the biggest barriers for users using this platform has always been people try to use it like a help desk when it isn't designed to be one. I expect future updates to generally lower the quality standards of the platform through changes in access to privilages (things like voting/closing) and tweaks to costs to further skew toward more content receiving upvotes. I don't however expect these changes alter why people are leaving, we ...

Comment: needed the upcoming changes many years ago, now it's probably a bit late after people have left/given up. We already know more changes are on the way.

Comment: it is time for humans to admit that AI is better, AI is the new deal. I told everybody that GPT is better and then they downvoted my post and turned me away. Now its costing someone millions of traffic drop because they didn't forward my warnings to the right team.

Comment: @Passionate If you seriously believe that GPT is better, I strongly urge you to spend more time learning how GPT actually works, and why it has the limitations that it does. I suggest starting here: https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/02/what-is-chatgpt-doing-and-why-does-it-work/

Comment: @PM2Ring, but did you know that its making SE employees to not sleep at night because of the compeitition.

Comment: @Passionate It's not clear what you're trying to say, but I suspect that you are saying that SE Inc is worried by the drop in people posting questions and answers since ChatGPT was released. However, numbers have been dropping for years, for a variety of reasons, ChatGPT has just accelerated that.

Comment: @PM2RING, will they ever recover from this, can chat GPT make SE obsolete?

Comment: @PM2RING, yeah that explains it but it's a more android (chat GPT) knocking off Symbian(SE) it's perch. Let's wait and see. Time will tell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254010/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-passionate-se).

Comment: @PassionateSE - I would provide you examples of the content that I have flagged in another community of mine, to say that the current version of OpenAI that ChatGPT uses, generates complete and total garbage would be an insult to an actual pile of garbage. OpenAI in its current form is unable to answer complicate questions, that detail descriptions, which is of course required for a human to understand and answer a question. One common ultimate to the garbage that OpenAI (ChatGPT) is generating, is that it will pick up on details within the question and start randomly talking about it.

Comment: @SecurityHound, maybe but it generates quality output that some users find beneficial in some specific programming contexts. Of course its not perfect, so are all tech devices made by humans.

Comment: @PassionateSE -I have reviewed lots of contributions generated by a LLM, I have not found a single one, that could be considered to be helpful. In order to get a LLM to generate code, that is helpful, the individual using the LLM must be already able to answer the programming question. Which begs the question, if the author of an answer is able to generate the answer themselves, why don't they just generate it themself? A former Microsoft Windows Engineer filmed a great video on YouTube on this subject, while he was able to get a LLM to generate quality code it took his own knowledge to do so.