# How is Stack Overflow Inc. prepared for a possible moderation strike by community elected moderators on June 5?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderation-strike

It has come to my attention that some community-elected moderators have decided to enact a moderation strike on Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network starting from the 5th of June.

This is very concerning considering that Stack Overflow is maintained by and heavily relies on moderators for the normal functioning of the site and for preventing spam and other unacceptable behavior. I have 2 main questions:

1. How is Stack Overflow Inc. prepared for this event?
2. Does it have the manpower to compensate for the shortage of moderators participating in the strike?

In the event of failure to compensate for the shortage:

1. How do you imagine the site without adequate moderation?
2. Could the site collapse in the process?

Comment: [«Moderators» also includes curators, answerers, flaggers, bots, moderation rooms and Charcoal](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/)

Comment: You’re also welcome to join the strike. :)

Comment: I suspect the answers to the first questions are: 1. No preparation. 2. No.

Comment: This is not actually the first time that a number of moderators across the network are restricting their activity. Back when the whole 2019 debacle happened, quite a few mods resigned at once. From what I can tell the whole deal back then was "Just make the CM team work 20 hours a day"

Comment: I would like to know if there is a possibility or risk of the CEO replacing the entire team of moderators with AI?

Comment: "Could the site collapse..." Probably not. One can imagine the site operating at smaller speed it with more errors for quite some time. That is unless the strike includes all or almost all moderators. At the very least older content isn't degrading so quickly without moderation.

Comment: To answer 2. If the strike goes on long enough, the network won't get out undamaged. However, an immediate collapse is unlikely and not the goal.

Comment: @AugustoVasques At this moment, AI is not capable of moderating SE sites properly. If the CEO is going to try it, I for one am going to buy a REALLY large bag of popcorn and watch the trainwreck.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Going off the last week it might be time to [invest](https://www.independent.co.uk/extras/indybest/house-garden/kitchen-accessories/best-popcorn-makers-a9374421.html)

Comment: It would be worthwhile to indicate the broad motivations for the strike.  If I understood correctly then I am 100% for it which also means I would rather see SO tank for a while till they address the concerns.

Comment: @blakkwater A strike *sometimes* also happens not to protect workers’ rights but rather to flag a risk to the larger community because management does not provide the workers with means and tools to serve the community’s interests.  This seems be the case here.  No SJW, or anti-SJW, or harm to moderators.  Just a bad moderation policy decision by SE management, whom I usually somewhat give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @JLP The broad motivations are covered under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979/, and it sounds like more detail may follow tomorrow.

Comment: @JLPeyret It's about much more than just the single AI policy. But that ended up being the main focus of the strike. Await a post on MSE in about 7 hours.

Comment: @JLPeyret Andreas posted a link to the open letter above, which outlines why we're doing this and what we want. I believe someone will be making a meta post that officially represents our position tomorrow, though I don't know who's responsible for that.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo We're a group of people writing the post right now. Hopefully, we'll manage to cover everything.

Comment: [The MSE post is now live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/357051)

Comment: *"This is very concerning considering that Stack Overflow is maintained by and heavily relies on moderators for the normal functioning of the site"* - yeah? We'll see I guess. They do a lot of good work, no doubt. If that good work has any kind of measurable impact at this point in site growth, I am very interested to find out.

Comment: "Site growth" isn't the only metric, though.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Our CEO is leading the way. https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/31/ceo-update-paving-the-road-forward-with-ai-and-community-at-the-center/

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**TL;DR** 1) probably not at all. 2) no. 3) imagine lots of garbage (particularly spam) that doesn't get handled nearly as fast as it should (if at all). 4) exceedingly unlikely. The network will suffer during the strike, but a lot/most of it can be cleaned up after the strike.

**Update:** The strike started as expected [on June 5th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000/6296561)

---

I'm not an employee, so I cannot answer #1 accurately. However, given the incredibly short amount of time between the initial planning phase and the start of the strike (planning started on the 30th, meaning 6 days between starting on a plan and the strike formally starting), I imagine the the answer is that they haven't prepared. Aside time, part of this boils down to the answer for #2.

As already mentioned in the comments, aside users, SOBotics, SOCVR, and Charcoal are expected to shut down, the latter of which has the single highest impact of the bunch. I don't have a source, but it has previously been stated that SO relies heavily on Charcoal for spam detection. Metasmoke, the server component of Charcoal that's also in charge of auto-flagging, went down for maintenance a couple days ago, and has already triggered questions about why spam is staying around for so long all of the sudden.<sup>2</sup>

This is with spam reports still being output to Charcoal HQ. Potentially no reports, and a significant reduction in flaggers via Charcoal (many of them are also joining the strike) is a recipe for a spam explosion, particularly when spammers notice it's down and decide to take advantage. The built-in spam protection systems are not remotely able to compete with Charcoal.

---

[At the time of writing](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), there are 192 signatures, 52 of which are from mods (accounting for 9.6% of the entire moderation team<sup>1</sup>), and the remaining 140 are from curators around the network. There's several sites without a significant part of their mod team left, SO included. 14/24 active SO mods are going on strike<sup>6</sup> (there are 27, but 3 are inactive for unrelated personal reasons), accounting for at least 80% of the work performed on SO.

There's also 3 sites fully without moderators at the time of writing, not accounting for inactive mods elsewhere in the network that may increase this number.<sup>5</sup>

All of these numbers are expected to grow over the next week, as we're still trying to get the word out to other mods. It'll also grow more during the weekdays, as some mods take time off during weekends. (It's unpaid work, it's not unreasonable to expect downtime)

For comparison, there's [14 CMs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/332043) (just 14, no missing zeroes), several of which have other priorities and tasks outside moderation that can't necessarily be paused. They might be able to offset some of the striking labour, but nowhere close to prevent a work shortage, especially because they're bound by ~8 hour work days and 5 day weeks in not enough timezones to cover entire days. Even if every single CM got reassigned to network moderation, they wouldn't be able to prevent the work shortage. Mods and curators combined are generally able to cover the site 24/7, especially when it comes to spam, thanks to SmokeDetector and the accompanying cross-site cooperation, and have experience with plenty of things that CMs do not.

They might be able to source other teams that I'm unaware of, but that would also mean sourcing likely inexperienced people to offset a significantly larger amount of significantly more experienced people. It doesn't add up in their favour.

Combined with the numbers of striking curators and mods growing, they don't have any chance of offsetting the labour. The only option aside this is hiring more people, but they're [likely not financially able to do so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389060/332043). This disregards the logistics of actually hiring people, and particularly the amount of time required for new hires to be operational on the site.

It's difficult to tell what the site will look like without moderation, but you can probably imagine lots and lots of unmoderated content floating around for longer than it should before it's handled, if it gets handled at all. Unhandled spam is likely going to be the biggest problem<sup>3</sup>, and it's also painfully visible.

A full collapse is unlikely. The network will struggle during the strike, yes, but when the strike ends, we'll be back to clean it up. The longer it goes on though, the more damage is done, some of which cannot be reversed. For the reversible damage, it will take a while to sort it out, but that's expected.

If it doesn't end, we might indeed be looking at a few collapse scenarios. I will not be speculating on what these may look like, because I like to think it won't come to that. It is exceedingly unlikely to happen due to the impact it'll have on particularly the company's reputation, and the potential for a financial impact for the company and by extension, its shareholders, who hold a lot of weight.

Also, neither side of this conflict wants a full collapse. The signals we've gotten from the company so far have been that they want to sort this out as quickly as possible, because an extended strike will have consequences for both the company and the sites in the network affected by the strike<sup>4</sup>. This doesn't guarantee any specific outcome (nor does it guarantee that certain outcomes won't happen), but it does reduce the likelihood of a collapse.

#### Footnotes

1: While it does account for 9.6% of the people, it does not account for 9.6% of moderation roles. Some moderators are mods on multiple sites. Though there are fewer of them than there are mods with just one diamond, they do exist, and aren't negligible. One of the more extreme examples of this is a striking moderator with 6 diamonds. See also [the list of moderators grouped by user](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users).

2: Mainly in the form of comments, though there's [at least one meta post](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9880/569995) elsewhere in the network.

3: It's hard to understate the importance of Charcoal for mitigating spam. Charcoal alone is responsible for the vast majority of spam detections and detection across the network. Taking it down has an enormous impact, especially given SE's severely lacking internal spam detection systems. They've previously added system-sided blocks for spammers, but ironically, the data used to determine what metrics makes sense comes from posts caught by Charcoal's bot [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector).

4: Likely all of them, due to SD being taken down, and many curators part of the cross-site effort it's based on also going on strike. SD significantly reduces the amount of mod work and work from that site's core users required to cope with spam, which means many smaller sites are going to struggle to keep spam under control, even if no mods go on strike.

5: Mods can mark themselves as inactive, but this is not publicly displayed, so there's no way to tell without data from the company. Essentially, a site with 2 mods and one striking mod could potentially be left with 0 mods, due to the second mod being inactive for a wide array of personal reasons. There's no way to tell or guesstimate based on the number of mods either, as there isn't an expected ratio between the number of active and inactive mods. Real-life circumstances causing inactivities are unpredictable.

6: Ahead of this, many of us have also cut back on moderation activities in general, which has resulted in the flag queue on SO jumping from the 100-200 flags it has been at for the past few weeks, straight up to 1.2k. This isn't even with a full stop in moderation activities, which starts tomorrow or already, depending on the timezone. You can imagine how much work the company would have to put in to SO alone to compensate for just SO mods going on strike. This is even prior to all the other shutdowns being accounted for.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm wondering if we should try to put as many mod-only flags as possible in the SO flag queue as we can. Even SO mods could help with that.

Comment: Why would we do that? @Laurel

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Because if the big flaggers go on strike, the CMs may not have an authentic experience modding here on SO. Anyway, it wouldn't be the first time they got overwhelmed trying to take on some of the work SO mods do, and hopefully it would persuade them to give into the demands (or use whatever influence they have to get the people above to).

Comment: It also depends on how long the strike goes on. Allowing the site's content deteriorate to the point where it is no longer valuable as a resource for solving problems might take a shorter time than you imagine.

Comment: @tripleee Could that lead to all SE sites going read-only, when the spammers discover they have free rein to post and tell all their spammer friends?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's certainly an option, but it would put the company in an extremely bad light to the rest of the world, and read-only in particular would further push the currently stabilised decline in traffic further down again. There's still lots of people who ask on SO. Fully preventing them is a death sentence for traffic and engagement

Comment: @AndrewMorton If the site was read only, then nobody can post, not even spammers. What's happening is that spam is being posted and not being deleted very fast. Maybe some of it won't be deleted at all. Somewhere on the network there's blatant spam that's even tagged [spam] that's been around for about a half hour already and that's on a site where there's a decent amount of people (at least measured by meta activity).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I'm 100% sure this wouldn't happen: if network will be at siege of spam, SE always have a possibility to rollback their *** policy. No policy will be protected till death of network (and readonly, even for a couple of days means exactly that: death to trust, traffic and engagement)

Comment: Regarding footnote 1: Is the "6" an upside down "9"? There seem to be two mods with 9 sites under their belt(s)

Comment: @Greenonline No. One of the mods who have signed up happens to be a mod on 6 sites. I never claimed that was the max of either the striking mods or total, just one I was aware of that had joined when I wrote this, and that had a significant number of diamonds.

Comment: Good luck to you all, and I hope you haven't just created a mountain of work if/when you return from strike action.

Comment: One day into the strike it doesn't seem to have much impact yet. The homepage of Stack Overflow looks fine, no spam, no off-topic questions, and no AI generated answers. Maybe slightly less downvoted and closed questions than normal. The number of people signing the open letter to join the strike is still growing, but I wonder how many are needed to make a difference in the question list.

Comment: @Marijn [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389885/158281) hints at an increase in GPT generated answers

Comment: It is worth noting that [staff has lowered the threshold for spam flags to 4 (down from the normal 6)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63742488#63742488). This will reduce the effort required to remove spam, possibly allowing the community to do it without moderator and/or Charcoal assistance.

Comment: I've definitely seen some uncaught spam that's persisted a few days that'd normally be cleaned up. Not really obvious "Phone this number for tech support" but accounts posting link only answers to blog posts by their dubious consulting company. I haven't flagged them for strike reasons

Comment: What is the reason behind this strike?

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000/6296561