# Should we [whisper] louder?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Currently, the following tags are confused by most users:

- [openai-whisper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-whisper)
- [whisper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whisper)

The first tag is for OpenAI voice recognition model, while the second wiki reads as

> Whisper is one of the components of Graphite, and is responsible for the back-end storage of incoming metrics from the network.

There are 70 questions tagged [whisper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whisper). Till this year the tag was used correctly, but now all questions asked in 2023 (24 in total, checked manually) are about transcription ML model. This can be explained by the fact that Whisper was released near Sep. 2022, and took a few months to grow in popularity.

Given the growing popularity of Whisper model, I suggest to rename [whisper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whisper) to [graphite-whisper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphite-whisper) before this becomes more messy. Existing questions would need to be cleaned before this (I already edited three and noticed the amount only after that).

Comment: Core curators are [on a strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425000/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an), so posting at this moment risks having your curation post buried, with no action.

Comment: Without "blacklisting" whisper, that'll just result in the tag getting recreated. It would possibly be better to rename the current tag to graphite-whisper, and then make whisper of synonym of openapi-whisper since that appears to be the primary usage.

Comment: Well, given that suggestions to blacklist a tag are usually rejected by mod team (for some technical reason, I don't recall exactly), using synonyms might be a great solution here. Thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas!

Comment: Worth mentioning that there's a Ruby gem/library called `whisper` as well.

Comment: I retagged all of the OpenAI Whisper questions to remove [tag:whisper] and add [tag:openai-whisper].

Comment: Agree with @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas that creating [tag:graphite-whisper], retagging all graphite whisper questions to it, and aliasing [tag:whisper] to [tag:openai-whisper] is the way to go.  You should make that an answer.  But unfortunately there are currently only [2 people](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/openai-whisper/topusers) with a rep of 5 or more in [tag:openai-whisper] so it may be impossible to do without mod help -- and most are on strike.

Comment: @dbc: If we remove all whisper questions I submit the alias can wait.

Comment: I would recommend against aliasing a generic tag (`[whisper]`) with a more specific one (`[openai-whisper]` or `[graphite-whisper]`), Regular users will continue to use the generic tag, (blissfully unaware, not noticing or simply not caring about the automatic rename), leading to ongoing mistagged questions. This has been [raised in the past as an issue with generic synonyms on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13756/107240).

Comment: In some more detail, when you add `[whisper]` as a tag, it gets silently replaced, and many users don't notice.

Comment: No, they aren't confused; the people using them just don't care to take 5 seconds of their day to read the descriptions and use the correct tag.

Comment: @Robotnik that question ends with [tag:msi-windows-installer] as a good solution that includes generic part to make users aware of the connection, and in our case [tag:openai-whisper] contains this part. Also, I bet 90% or more of questions next year will ask about ML model and not a Graphite component, which is very industry-specific and had only ~50 questions since 2014. I'm sure users who ask about [tag:graphite-whisper] and try to tag with [tag:whisper] will indeed notice that their tag was substituted with [tag:openai-whisper] and fix this.

Comment: The issue with [tag:whisper] recreation sounds much more realistic and troublesome to me compared to accidental misuse for Graphite questions.

Comment: @IanKemp you're correct of course, but it's the reality and we have to deal with it somehow. This ML models will certainly attract many newcomers who definitely won't read tag wikis, as usual, so something has to be done to prevent new mistagged questions from appearing.

Comment: To highlight the importance of this, 2 hours ago was asked yet another question about speech recognition tagged [tag:openai-api] and [tag:whisper]. I already replaced the wrong tag, but it clearly shows the tendency.