# How should I handle a question with a non-English title?

Tags: discussion, flags, title, languages, english

There's the following flag:

> Not written in English
>
> Use this close reason if the question is not written in English. Do
> not use this close reason for questions that are primarily written in
> English but happen to contain non-English variable names, error
> messages, or other short excerpts.

If the title is not written in English, but the rest of the question is "primarily written in English", then it doesn't fit this flag.
Should I take any action then? Is there a specific flag for this case? Are non-English titles acceptable on Stack Overflow if the question is written in English?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For something like this, it seems that leaving a comment to advise the user to edit their question and use English text for the title would be appropriate. You may wish to link them to the help centre article [Can I ask a question in a language other than English?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) as well, which explains why they need to use English.

If they don't respond/edit the question in a timely manner, or if you simply just want to improve the post anyway, then doing your own edit to the post to provide an English title would be more than appropriate. Likely you would be better off writing a title based on the content of the question, rather than putting the content into a translator and copy and pasting that. If the user doesn't like that title, they can always edit it again later.

Answer (score 29):

If you know from the question body what a suitable title would be then edit it yourself. If you can't tell what the question is asking, then vote to close.

Answer (score -6):

As of right now, you should [join the moderation strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425000/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) and do nothing.

After Stack Exchange starts cooperating with the community again, you can either edit the title yourself (since the OP clearly knows English at least well enough to be able to write the question and can presumably respond to comments and answers) or ask the OP to do so.