# Add flagging AI generated answers

Tags: feature-request, flags

AI generated answers are prohibited but no flagging option exists. I think the flag should be added.

Comment: AI generated content is effectively unbanned. That’s the main reason why [we’re striking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425000/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an). As such, there will be no flags, because the company has embraced this garbage, and want it to flood their sites.

Comment: @pierpy they still are. It’s just impossible to enforce.

Comment: Saying that no flagging option exists is inaccurate. It's unclear to me from your question if you just don't understand what you're supposed to do, or if you're asking for the creation of a new flag type because you know how to currently flag, but you feel it's not sufficient/convenient. Please [edit] your question to clarify. As has always been the case, if there's an issue which doesn't fit into one of the named flags, then you should raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag and explain the issue. For AI generated content, you should *explain why you think the post is AI generated*.

Comment: related on MSE: [New flag for ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388587/997587)

Answer (score 22):

Don't you get it? AI is the future! It will replace us mere developers and answerers and bring a whole 4.4 trillion dollars into the economy by sheer magic.

Companies are pouring billions into it in the hopes of yielding that money back a hundredfold, if not more. Because who doesn't want a bland amalgamation of all sentences ever written, and then remixed somewhat?

In order for all those plans to work, the first thing we need is mass adoption. Given Stack Overflow houses millions of those soon-to-be replaced developers, the company *must* allow GPT-generated answers to remain on the site.

tl;dr: no.

I would say /s for sarcasm, but given the past couple of actions by Stack Overflow (banning AI suspensions, putting questions through ChatGPT to """format""" them and posting blog after blog claiming AI is the next best thing since sliced bread), I really don't know where we stand. I wouldn't get my hopes up.

To answer the question: if you don't want to partake in the strike and refrain from flagging, then use a custom mod flag explaining that the post appears to be generated by ChatGPT or the likes.

Comment: This is completely incomprehensible for those that don't know what's currently going on here... (And I hate fun)

Comment: I really don't care at this point. Also, one must have been living under an AI-generated rock not to know that. (lol@edit). Hope my edit clarifies somewhat.

Comment: You’d be surprised to learn how many people live under rocks.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid raising custom mod flags during the strike. If anything, this is helpful to the strike's goals, as it serves to underscore the work done by and thus need for moderators.