# Spam link added to an answer a few days after the initial posting

Tags: discussion, spam

Previously, a user answered my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478309/what-is-the-limit-of-google-chat-message-card-via-chatbot/76640682#76640682), but it was later deleted as I reported it as spam. Initially, the answer did not really answer my question, only like rewrite my question and answer, and there was no link provided. However, after a few days, the user edited the answer and added a link.

Similarly, another user answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76619861/2671470), and initially, there was no link in the answer. But later, the user edited the answer and included a link.

I'm not certain if the links in both cases are the same, as I cannot see the deleted answer and have forgotten the link. However, it is evident that both answers used similar techniques, which could be considered spam.

Are these techniques becoming more popular on Stack Overflow nowadays?

Comment: The second answer didn't just add a link, it is the exact same text after the first answer's edit. So you might be correct, that both cases are the same. I would say it is the same person doing that.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> Are these techniques becoming more popular on Stack Overflow nowadays?

Nope, it's been happening for years.  The community-run anti-spam group [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) (disclosure: in which I've been an active participant) is pretty good at catching this sort of thing once the spam link is edited in, but their bot is offline due to the [ongoing moderation strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) (more information on Meta Stack Overflow [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000/208273) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979/208273)).  It's a common enough technique that Charcoal has a specific tag for keeping track of spam domains with a reputation for doing it.

Thus, spam that would normally be zapped pretty quickly is sticking around longer.  Hopefully the conditions resulting in the strike will be resolved soon and we can all get back to nuking this spam from orbit as soon as it shows up.

Comment: *It's the only way to be sure.*